# How to add excerpt_more filter to this Excerpt code Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

This is the code which edit the excerpt to show only the first paragraph from the content. However, it doesn't have "Read More" link at the end of the paragraph.

Therefore, I'm wondering how I can add the excerpt_more filter to this code?

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
    if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    }
    return $text;
}
```

And this is the code that I'm hoping to add to this code above.

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Read more here.', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

That way, you can customize the "read more" link with any words you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : Need to create custom wp_trim_excerpt filter.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) )
{
    function custom_wp_trim_excerpt($excerpt) 
    {
        global $post;
        $raw_excerpt = $excerpt;
        if ( $excerpt == '' ) 
        {
            $excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $excerpt );
            $excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);
            $excerpt = substr( $excerpt, 0, strpos( $excerpt, '</p>' ) + 4 );

            $excerpt_readmore = ' &raquo; <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">Read More</a>';
            $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_readmore);

            $pos = strrpos($excerpt, '</');
            if ($pos !== false)
                $excerpt = substr_replace($excerpt, $excerpt_readmore, $pos, 0);
            else
                $excerpt .= $excerpt_readmore;

                return $excerpt;
        }
        return apply_filters('custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```